# Passing empty object as an argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice'];

var countedNames = names.reduce(function(allNames, name) { 
  if (name in allNames) {
    allNames[name]++;
  }
  else {
    allNames[name] = 1;
  }
  return allNames;
}, {});
```

In the last line why have they passed an empty object to the reduce function.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? That is the initial value and on top of it result would be constructed

Comment: [rtfm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered by reading the documentation for reduce. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Because last param of reduce is 'initial value'  and they start with an empty object which reduce will fill up with counters. You should check how reduce works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @epascarello sometimes the docs aren't sufficient to explain something, especially as this is a (very) slightly unusual use of `.reduce`

Comment: @Alnitak And reduce is pretty clear...I learned how to use it by MDN.

Comment: Think about what the value of `allNames` is.

Answer (score -1):

The final argument to `.reduce` is the "seed" value that's used as the initial value in the first iteration for the first parameter passed to the callback.

In this usage, the `.reduce` function is filling that initially empty object with the count of each unique value observed, and then returning that same object (now modified) as the next value ready for the next iteration.

Comment: down-vote all you like - I've made this answer community wiki

Comment: Would be helpful if the people who downvoted also provide information on _why_ they downvote.